# How to get 'verify SID' in Twilio?

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have created an account in twilio and got SID and auth token. Where can I find the 'verify SID token' which is used for otp verification.

Comment: Do you refer to the SID of the Verify service? I'm a bit confused about the term "SID Token".

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can see all your [Verify Service SID's in your console here at this link](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/verify/services)!

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, do we need to save the "VEXXX" Verification SID from the Verify API response? And then return that to our app's frontend, and have the frontend submit it with the 6 digit OTP submitted by the user, for better security? It seems like we were encouraged to save and submit the Authy ID from the old API, but I can't find any info about this extra security step for Verify (it seems to be undocumented). Or is the Verification SID just meant for manual approval by an admin, for example by saving it in the database and showing it in an app's admin panel? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the SID of the Verify service in the console under "[Verify > Service](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/verify/services)" and then in the table displayed there.

[image]

And then you can use this snippet from the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification) to use the service:

```php
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$verification = $twilio->verify->v2->services("VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                                   ->verifications
                                   ->create("+15017122661", "sms");

print($verification->sid);
```